# selecting records limited by only those with both criteria met

Tags: mysql

OK, the title is confusing but let me explain. 
Let's say that I have a employee skills database for which I would like managers to be able to search through.

A manager may want to search for employees with nunchuck skills... 
Ok, great, thats easy:

```
SELECT * FROM skilllist WHERE skillname= "nunchuck"
```

Bam! I got a list of employees with nunchuck skills.

But say a manager would like to get a list of employees with both "nunchuck" skills and "bow staff" skills. How can I create a query like that? I can't just say:

```
SELECT * FROM skilllist WHERE skillname= "nunchuck" AND skillname= "bow staff"
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM skilllist WHERE skillname= "nunchuck" OR skillname= "bow staff"
```

The latter would just return all employees with nunchuck skills and all employees with bow staff skills. I would like to get ONLY employees with both skills. I can't figure it out. Please help! :)

Comment: It appears Employee-to-Skill is a many-to-many relationship.  That suggests there is more than one table.  Your SQL presents it otherwise.  That suggests your query process will be problematic.  Can you provide more details on the structure?

Comment: Sure, here is the table structure for skilllist:

listid
memberid
divisionid
categoryid
skillid
proficiency

This table holds a list for all skills entered for each employee. listid is a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from employees where 
employeeID in (select memberID from skilllist where skillname = 'nunchuck') and 
employeeID in (select memberID from skilllist where skillname = 'bow staff')
```

Comment: Closest to what i needed. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** From clearly incorrect first response where I was too speedy in reading the post.

You could group by employee and count, where the count = the number of skills your looking for. This assumes there's no skill duplication. This is the syntax I would use for MSSQL, so might be slightly different for MySQL.

```
SELECT [EmployeeName], Count(1) FROM 
skilllist 
WHERE skillname in ( "nunchuck","bow staff")
Group By [EmployeeName]
Having Count(1) = 2
```

Comment: This is the same problem as using AND.  It will return those that have either nunchuck or bow staff.

Comment: huh.. will this not work? I think the 'having' clause will return only those who have both the skills. Am I missing something here?

Comment: the previous comments were from the previous revisions of this post.

Comment: Sorry, I should have indicated that it was edited due to doltery on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with Smandoli.

But then you have to compare the id's and expand your Query-Statement with an AND clause:

```
SELECT * FROM skilllist WHERE skillname= "nunchuck" AND skillname= "bow staff" AND table1.id=table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
Select *
  from employees
 where 1 < (select count(*) 
              from skilllist 
             where slilllist.emp_id = employees.emp_id 
               and skillname in ('nunchuck','bow staff') )
```

However, it hard codes the amount of skills.  So if you now added a third choice you would have to increase the 1 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from employees
RIGHT JOIN skilllist s1 ON s1.memberid = employees.id AND s1.skillname = "nunchuck"
RIGHT JOIN skilllist s2 ON s2.memberid  = employees.id AND s2.skillname = "bow staff"
```

...

Answer (score 0):

The following query will list the ids of the employees having both the skillsets,

```
select employee_id, count(skillname) 
from skilllist 
where skillname in ('nunchuck','bow staff') 
group by employee_id having count(skillname) > 1;
```